# Integrate Fiddler With Selenium RC To Capture HTTP Headers

Tags: selenium, proxy, fiddler

I'm trying to use Fiddler 4.6.2.3 as the proxy for Selenium RC (the standalone server .jar file v2.53.0) in Firefox instead of Selenium RC's built-in proxy.  I'm doing this because I want to take advantage of Fiddler's capabilities.  I have Fiddler working correctly with Firefox for both HTTP and HTTPS.  I have Selenium RC working correctly with the "*firefox" profile using the standalone Selenium RC server .jar file.  **What I'd like to do is replace Selenium's built-in proxy with Fiddler.**

I am launching both Fiddler and Selenium RC from the same .BAT file.  I launch Fiddler first, then launch a test suite using the Selenium RC standalone server.  When I remark out the Fiddler launch in the .BAT file, the Selenium RC test suite executes perfectly.  When I launch Fiddler, then launch the Selenium RC test suite (both from the .BAT file), Selenium RC complains that Fiddler's security certificate is a problem and the Selenium RC test suite fails.

I'm new to the world of automated testing and Selenium.  I've tried using the Selenium RC command line option `-avoidProxy` to see if Selenium RC would somehow "find" Fiddler if it was instructed not to use its built-in proxy.  That doesn't work - Selenium RC still complains about the Fiddler security certificate.  I also tried using the Selenium RC `-trustAllSSLCertificates` command line option.  That solved the Fiddler certificate problem by completely bypassing Fiddler altogether, which of course prevented the capture of any HTTP and HTTPS traffic by Fiddler.

What I would like to happen is the following:

1. Launch Fiddler
2. Launch and run the Selenium RC test suite
3. Fiddler captures all HTTP and HTTPS traffic as the test suite runs
4. Use FiddlerScript to export specific headers to a file for later analysis (I know how to do this)
5. Close Selenium
6. Close Fiddler

It feels like I've almost got this solution working.  Does anyone know how to "connect" Fiddler to Selenium RC.  BTW - I know that Selenium RC has supposedly been deprecated in favor of Selenium 2.0 WebDriver.  However, the Selenium Website says that Selenium RC is still being maintained and is a usable product, within its constraints.  I don't have a need to develop this solution in WebDriver, so if it's possible to replace Selenium RC's proxy with Fiddler that's what I prefer to do.

Thanks In Advance For Your Help -

Answer (score 0):

You can use FiddlerCore in your .NET code.
Look here: [FiddlerCore API by Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore)

Comment: Thanks, @Legends, for the suggestion.  I am trying to avoid the FiddlerCore route for now due to my unfamiliarity with .NET.  I would have to learn .NET JScript to make FiddlerCore work. I am trying to see if I can make the less-complicated Selenium RC solution work with Fiddler.